# gsap ( Scroll Trigger ) Animation is not working

Tags: gsap, scrolltrigger

The Gsap animation wont work

```
<body>
    <div id="landingpage">
        <embed id="landingSVG" src="assets/laptopLanding.svg" type="image/svg+xml"/>
        <div id="homepage" > </div>
    <div id="more"> </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

this a embedded svg file
I want to scale it up on scroll
why is this code not working

```
import { gsap } from "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/gsap.min.js";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js";

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

window.onload = () => {
  const tl = gsap.timeline({
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: "#landingpage",
      pin: true, 
      start: "top top", 
      end: "+=100%", 
      scrub: true, 
    }
  });

  tl.to("#landingSVG", {
    scale: 2, 
    ease: "none"
  });
};
```

also if it works it will zoom in on the center
tell me a way to zoom in on a particular part of this svg